# Ubuntu 18.04.3 ieee80211.h not found

Tags: linux, header, libpcap, packet-sniffers

I'm working on libpcap to make my own wireless networking sniffer, and I want to include  in my program, the compile failed with the error message "fatal error: ieee80211.h: no such file or directory".
The kernel version is 5.3.0-28-generic, I believe it's quite new and I couldn't find any ieee80211.h file in normal include paths such as /usr/include, /usr/include/linux, and even if I include it from somewhere else, more errors come out because it includes much more sources that don't exist.
it seems that I have to install the complete networking source code system.

Is there any way i can do that?

Comment: ieee80211.h is located at `/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28/include/linux/ieee80211.h` .... Package : https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-headers-5.3.0-28

Comment: Hi Knud, i specified the full path of ieee80211.h, but this header file includes for example the etherdevice.h, which can not be found again. I mean, the including works really complicated, and i just want them to be installed in the regular include path so that i don't need to specify the paths one by one, is there any way i can do that?